# Assigning Slider to Horizontal Paging (like Instagram) - UISlider to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uislider

I have a horizontal paging, and I am trying to achieve a UISlider being connected to page position like the one Instagram has on its Activity screen. This is what I've achieved so far.

I have added a `Navigation Bar` at the top, `UIView` under that with buttons inside, `UISlider`, and a `UIScrollView` with 2 `UITableView` in the subViews of `UIScrollView`. (First of all, is that a good approach?)

First, this is my code for those who are trying to achieve the same thing:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let V1 : TableView0 = TableView0(nibName: "TableView0", bundle: nil)

    self.addChildViewController(V1)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(V1.view)
    V1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    let V2 :TableView1 = TableView1(nibName: "TableView1", bundle: nil)

    self.addChildViewController(V2)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(V2.view)
    V2.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    var V2Frame : CGRect = V2.view.frame
    V2Frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
    V2.view.frame = V2Frame

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width * 2, self.view.frame.height)

}
```

What I want to achieve is, connecting the `UISlider` to the page position (as the one at the very bottom of the screen / scroll-position) like the one Instagram has. This is what I've achieved so far, but I couldn't figure out how to connect slider to page position:

[image]

What Instagram has: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that you are able to achieve that with UISlider.
I think the easiest solution will be customizing ScrollView indicator, and probably Instagram used this approach. You can refer to this to libraries: [CustomScrollIndicator](https://github.com/leverdeterre/CustomScrollIndicator), [JTSScrollIndicator](https://github.com/jaredsinclair/JTSScrollIndicator).

You can also create custom view (indicator) and position according to scrollView contentOffset. To get contentOffset implement `UIScrollViewDelegate` method:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
      // use scrollView.contentOffset.x
}
```

Comment: I think the best bet would be using a library. Thanks